# Visual Studio 2015 html and css live preview

Tags: html, css, visual-studio

Is HTML and CSS live preview available in Visual Studio 2015? if so, how to activate it?
if not is there any plugin for Visual Studio 2015 to use this feature?

Comment: For VS 2017+, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48948256/visual-studio-2017-html-previewer

Answer (score 0):

I found a plugin in the Visual Studio Marketplace. The name of the plugin is Live HTML Previewer. Here is [the link](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=hdg.live-html-previewer)

Comment: this is for Visual Studio Code not Visual Studio 2015

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is an out-of-the-box feature in Visual Studio to do this (I don't do much web development), but a quick Google search returned these extensions that might help you:

- [Live HTML Previewer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=hdg.live-html-previewer)
- [HTML Preview](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tht13.html-preview-vscode)
- [Web Essentials](http://vswebessentials.com/) - This one I've actually seen before, and know to be quite powerful

Answer (score 0):

You could right-click on your project name and check if it offers an option for 'Page Inspector'.

If it does and you select it, it will open a panel on visual studio that shows your app as it would show in a browser with the html below in a separate section of the panel as well as a separate section for the style, etc.

Similar to what you see when you open developer tools on a browser, but with a preview included.

While you can't change the code in the panel's html section, you can make changes to your actual project files and update the preview by clicking the yellow notification bar indicating that the files have changed.

You can even expand or reduce the preview panel, and if you app is responsive, it will be responsive in the panel as well.