# Visual Studio 2017 HTML Previewer

Tags: html, visual-studio

I'm coding on VS2017 using HTML and I am looking for a way to see my website change as I code - a live previewer. I know there is one for VS Code:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=hdg.live-html-previewer

Is there one like this for VS2017 and where can I find it?

EDIT - I am looking for an extension like this, not the HTML designer. So as I code, I can see the website change much like the linked extension for VS Code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is the visual studio HTML Designer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31654960/where-is-the-visual-studio-html-designer)

Comment: @CalvinNunes Please see the edit.

Comment: The solution in the comment above did not work for me.  If I open an HTML page in the Web Forms editor in VS 2017 I see nothing but a blank page, no design or source views and not even my HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the "preview" is simply running the page which you can do by right clicking on it (either the code or the listing in the solution explorer) and selecting "View in Browser".  It'll open the file in a browser.  My common method then of seeing changes quickly has been to just keep refreshing when I save changes.  The good thing is that it'll be a really accurate portrayal of how the given browser will render what you just did.  No need to worry about whether the previewer is good enough.

But I found your question when I was looking for ways to preview how a page will look on a mobile device.  In case there's a listing on the page I found that might help you further, Microsoft has this page...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mobile/device-simulators

In case the link breaks, you might find the article again with the title: "Simulate Popular Mobile Devices for Testing".

Answer (score 0):

I've recently released [HTML 11](https://vlasovstudio.com/html11/) extension for Visual Studio 2017/2019 to quickly preview html files as you code:

[image]